# Лямбда функция и захват

Tags: c++

1st:

```
const uint32_t Size = 2048;
Ref<Max> env = Max::Create( Size); // static fn
FN::Submit([env, Size]()
    {
        MakeFJF(env->GetID(), Size);
    });
```

2nd:

```
const uint32_t Size = 2048;
Ref<Max> env = Max::Create(Size); // static fn
FN::Submit([=]()
    {
        MakeFJF(env->GetID(), Size);
    });
```

Насколько я знаю, есть какая-то разница, связанная с временем жизни переменных при захвате функции с помощью `=` и просто перечислением переменных. Подскажите,пожалуйста, в чем эта разница более подробно :)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что есть разница?

Comment: В данном синтаксисе нет разницы. В обоих случаях эти переменные захватываются по значению (как копии). Хорошая статья по лямбдам https://habr.com/ru/post/66021/